# Auto update frontend AJAX script modification with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the script below that works great but want to modify it for a desired effect. Right now it only works on initial page load. But how can I edit it to make it auto-feed every 30 seconds or so?

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "Administration/data/people.xml"
    }).done(function (xml) {
      $(xml).find('fullName').each(function() {
        var fullName = $(this).text();
        $('<button type="button" class="mybutton" name="users" onclick="showUser(this.value)"></button>').attr('value', fullName).html(fullName).appendTo('#loadMe');
      });
    }).fail(function (response, error) {
      $('#info').text('Error!');
    });
```

EDIT: 1/24/14 3:55 AM

I added the interval function, but now it is on an infinite loop and is not overwriting, but instead adding over and over again.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setInterval(updateMe,1000);

            function updateMe(){

        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "Administration/data/people.xml"
        }).done(function (xml) {
          $(xml).find('fullName').each(function() {
            var fullName = $(this).text();
            $('<button type="button" class="mybutton" name="users" onclick="showUser(this.value)"></button>').attr('value', fullName).html(fullName).appendTo('#loadMe');
          });
        }).fail(function (response, error) {
          $('#info').text('Error!');
        });


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) function to call the function every 30000 miliseconds.

Comment: Jerodev, I added the jQuery `setInterval` function but it is still not working quite right, I modified my question above, could you please take another look? Thanks!

Comment: You have to empty the parent element before adding more children. Use $("#loadMe").empty() before entering your loop.

Comment: jerodev, actually it works prettymuch anywhere inside the function. Thanks a lot! This is what I wanted for sure.

Comment: jerodev, one slight problem... There is a flicker of the data between intervals, how is this normally handled?

Comment: disregard the flicker question ^, there are some fade effects I am playing with that are resolving the issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

have a look at javascript `setInterval ()`

Plenty of examples on the web but the basic syntax is

`var intervalID = window.setInterval(code, delay);`

Comment: user2310289, I used the jQuery setInterval function, it is updated in my question above, but it is still not quite right. Any thoughts or hints? Thanks!